# Find the volume of the carbon dioxide product

Tags: physical-chemistry, stoichiometry

Below you can see the chemical reaction I'm working with:

$$\ce{CH_3CH_2OH(l) + 3O_2(g) -> 2CO_2 (g) + 3H_2O(g)}$$

I've got so far:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zgNk.png]

How can I calculate the volume of the product of carbon dioxide gas (the pressure is 1 bar, and the temperature is 20 deg Celsius).

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to determine the limiting reactant. Use the equation and the number of moles of $\ce{CH_3CH_2OH}$ and $\ce{O_2}$.

   In the reaction, you need 1 mol of $\ce{CH_3CH_2OH}$ and 3 mol of $\ce{O_2}$ to get 2 mol of $\ce{CO_2}$. If you have less than 1 mol of $\ce{CH_3CH_2OH}$ but 3 mol of $\ce{O_2}$, you cannot get 2 mol of $\ce{CO_2}$. In such a case, $\ce{CH_3CH_2OH}$ is the limiting reactant. The amount of $\ce{CO_2}$ will thus be lower than 2 mol.
2. Using the number of moles of the limiting reactant, you should be able to calculate the number of moles of $\ce{CO_2}$ produced. Use proportions!
3. The last step will involve using the ideal gas equation, by assuming that $\ce{CO_2}$ behaves like an ideal gas. $$PV=nRT$$

   You have the pressure $P$, the temperature $T$, $n$ (the number of moles of the $\ce{CO_2}$), $R$ is a constant. Find the volume $V$.

Comment: If you'd like to take the time, i would like to know what the exact answer to my question is, i mean - the result.

Comment: @FrederikWitte You're not trying to use the site to get your homework done, are you?

Comment: Just a side note: Pressure is usually referred to with a small $p$.

Comment: @Martin It can be represented [by both](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure).

Comment: @Jerry, you are right. IUPAC goldbook suggests a small [$p$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.P04819).